# Hotel Bills not settled by the company

Tags: accommodation, hotels

My company provided an allowance for accommodation; and the company's manager had booked the room on his card for two occupants.

After few days my friend vacated the room as the event work was over but the person who reserved the room didn't checkout and he is missing.

Now the hotel's staff are calling every visited guest and my friend and saying to pay the bill.

What can my friend can do in this situation?

Comment: Have you contacted the company and said that those people could have problems if they don't pay?

Comment: Does the hotel have anything precluding your friend from following Calchas' advice and simply leaving? (i.e. do they have his passport, etc) If not, he should provide that information and leave. If they do, he's in a bad situation. It may come to him being the last man standing and having to pay the bill. His only recourse in that situation will be to follow-up with the company on his own and if they give him the run around as well, sue them for costs.

Comment: There is a difference between reserving a room and agreeing to pay for it.  My company often has someone reserve rooms which they expect you to pay for (and then claim back from the company) Your question doesn't make clear whether the company manager was expected to pay for the rooms.

Comment: First off there are 200+ countries in the world can we at least narrow it down to one?  2nd If there is a credit card attached to the room it would be charged unless this was cancelled.  3rd The person who was in the room with your friend is missing how?   Physically missing or just ignoring the calls?

Comment: You might try asking this on [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DJClayworth Not really a Workplace question.

Answer (score 2):

This is dangerously close to being a legal question, but let's try to answer it. I'm also assuming your friend is no longer at the hotel.

If your friend didn't book the room, then it shouldn't be his responsibility to pay. However I'm guessing he signed something when he checked in that will make him liable. And from the hotel's point of view, if they didn't get paid they will pursue anyone they think they might be able to get to pay. Here's my recommendation:

1. Tell the hotel you didn't book the room, and that as far as you know the company manager was still occupying the room when yo left and was going to pay.
2. Be as helpful to the hotel as you can. Give them contact info for the manager. Give them contact info for the company.
3. Contact the company and tell them what happened. Ask them what they want to do. Ideally they should sort this out for you, by having someone call the hotel.  They may ask you to pay the bill for them, but I wouldn't recommend that unless the company tells you *in writing* that they will reimburse you, and preferably not even then.
4. If the hotel keeps bugging you, keep telling them it's the company's responsibility. Without your credit card info there is little they can realistically do. (If it gets to legal action that's going to be off-topic on this forum).

Answer (score 0):

Explain that the company is paying the bill and provide the hotel with the company's contact details.

Comment: If the company is not responding to calls and the friend is last man standing, it may not be this easy. He could try to just leave, but he may also face charges by the local police for absconding.